# Is there any use case where using a non capturing group is needed?

Tags: regex

Considering an example where I have a list of file names, along with their sizes, in every line -

```
file1.jpg   100
file-new.png    201
files.gif   102
exec.exe    200
```

**If I were to replace all of them (file name as well as size) which were jpg/gif/png**, I could use this regex -

```
/.+(jpg|png|gif)\t[\d]+/g
```

or this (using a non capturing group) -

```
/.+(?:jpg|png|gif)\t[\d]+/g
```

and in both cases, the following replacement pattern -

```
replaced
```

would output the following -

```
replaced
replaced
replaced
exec.exe    200
```

**Also, if I were to replace only the names of the files (keeping the extensions and sizes same)**, I could use this -

```
/(.+)(jpg|png|gif)(\t[\d]+)/g
```

And use the following replacement pattern  -

```
new name.$2$3
```

And I would get -

```
new name.jpg    100
new name.png    201
new name.gif    102
exec.exe    200
```

Using a non-capturing group in this case could allow me to get the thing done by using one less variable in the replacement pattern  -

```
/(.+)((?:jpg|png|gif)\t[\d]+)/g
```

Replacement -

```
new name.$2
```

***So far, I don't see any use case where I would have to use a non capturing group  otherise the functionality would not be achieved. Am I correct or am I missing something?***

*Note -*

*- I know there could be multiple ways of solving a problem using regex. If only one of the solutions to a problem involves a non-capturing group, I would still consider it a valid scenario because solving in that particular way needs a non capturing group.*

*- You may demonstrate a different problem in order to explain the use case.*

Comment: you can use capturing groups everywhere you like(_and replace accordingly_), but that increases overhead..and what is the need of capturing something when its not needed or is even bigger part of match

Comment: When you need to add an optional sequence to an existing pattern so as not to ruin backreferencing.

Comment: In some languages, a noncapturing group is convenient (as in Scala). In Perl, it is considered ok to even wrap tje whole pattern in a back reference if you need to reference the  whole pattern match. Your question sounds rather off topic.

Comment: As an aside, you mean `\d+` instead of `[\d]+` - the character class doesn't add anything, and is mildly confusing.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, care to explain? @WiktorStribiżew do you mean my question should be linked to a language to be on topic? Sorry, I did not completely get your 2nd comment.

Comment: My second comment is driving at the fact that there are multiple good answers, and none will be perfect. I do not know what a correct answer should sound like for this type of question. It should be the other way round: you have a regex, it does not work, but adding a non-capturing group we can fix it. Then, we can say why a non-capturing group is important. Not the way: "when is it good to use"?

Answer (score 1):

What if your file names are required to contain "one", "two", or "three"?

```
one-file.jpg   100
file-two.png    201
other-file.gif   102
three-file.exe    200
```

Now a non-capturing group is useful

```
/.*(?:one|two|three).*\.(jpg|png|gif)(\t[\d]+)/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use regular, capturing parentheses for *clustering* purposes as well. No regex is going to fail/succeed to match based on choice of capturing vs non-capturing parentheses, assuming you *aren't using [back-references](http://www.dustindiaz.com/regular-expression-back-matching)* in the regex itself, of course:

```
/((hello) (world)) \1/     //=>\1 equals "hello world" (pattern matches 'hello world hello world')
/((hello) (world)) \2/     //=>\2 equals "hello" (pattern matches 'hello world hello')
/((hello) (world)) \3/     //=>\3 equals "world" (pattern matches 'hello world world')
/(?:(?:hello)) (world) \2/   //=>\2 does not exist, pattern fails.(only \1 exists and equals 'world'
```

How you decide to group/capture also effects the resulting match object. If your goal is to parse your input, a successful match is not enough.

Consider the string *"3/0.125"* - you want to split this arithmetic operation into it's constituent tokens: 3, /, and 0.125.

3 variations on a regex to do this:

1) with both named groups, and non-capturing groups:

```
(?<operand1>(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))(?<operator>[+\/\*-])(?<operand2>(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))
```

[image]

2) or without the named groups:

```
((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))([+\/\*-])((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))
```

[image]

3) with no named or non-capturing groups:

```
((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))([+\/\*-])((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))
```

[image]

clearly your output, not to mention the regex itself, is not very sensible when you just roll with regular `()`'s.

Comment: Your examples demonstrate that using capturing groups increases the number of matches. I understand that it can increase overhead. I am not clear how the use of back-references is going to change the fail/success factor. Could you please demonstrate with an example?

Comment: I added some examples. the back-references link is a pretty straightforward explanation of using backrefs.

Comment: That back-references link contains something which I can not understand :D. I did understand whatever has been explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEmYvBDWpwE.